# Need to extract the text occuring between first two single quotes.

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
610640436 06/10/2014 03:01:05 AM 1 CLOSED Task 'LGSP_J_JOB_GSP_JP_FIN_CO_0000_SumLv3' erred in process 'LGSP_J_SAP_D_D_011' (6534399)
```

From this, I want to get the text occurring between the first two single quotes, so that the output in Excel should be  `LGSP_J_JOB_GSP_JP_FIN_CO_0000_SumLv3`

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("'",A1)+1,FIND("'",A1,FIND("'",A1)+1)-FIND("'",A1)-1)
```

Comment: My columns are K and M